# Current function of voltage, Taylor series

Tags: electric-current, voltage

Why can the current as a function of voltage for any device be written as a taylor series? Is it because voltage can be written as V0 Cos wt and then I = V/R ? I'm confused on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any physical quantity, if it can be expressed as a function that has all its' derivatives at a single point, can be expressed as a [Taylor Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series)